# Insert data to non fixed column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to make a trigger to insert data to non-fixed column.

I have tried with this code:

```
create trigger UPPLANtoTOTAL 
on [UP_PLAN]
for insert
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @ucode varchar(10) = (select CODE from inserted)
    declare @dd int = (select dd from UP_PLAN where CODE = @ucode)
    declare @qty decimal(18, 9) = (select QTY from UP_PLAN where CODE = @ucode)

    insert into TOTAL (CODE, COL + @dd + ) 
    values (@ucode, @qty)
end
```

But SQL Server shows an error:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: You can't refer columns with strings. You need to make a complete dynamic SQL for that. Also, inserted / deleted tables contain **all** the rows of the operation, not just one.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `declare @ucode varchar(10) = (select CODE from inserted)` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**.

Answer (score 0):

James Z is right you cannot do it like that. Try building your query as a string and then execute it with `EXECUTE` or `sp_executesql` or whatever fits best. But such things tend to point to a flaw in the database design. Maybe that's improvable and the need for that dynamic SQL can be avoided after all.

Comment: thank you all for your support.I will try @sticky bit suggestion